# Gurobi, Robust Optimization, Demand Uncertainty

Tags: python, gurobi, uncertainty

I have a robust optimization problem with uncertain demands d (100 demand arrays, each of length t) in a set D. I'm using Gurobi Optimizer to solve it/maximize the objective. Now my problem is, I want to define a Gurobi variable x for demand that can only take values based on the existing demand arrays in D. I am not sure how to implement this. Would I define the gurobi variable as continuous and then somehow create a constraint that allows only one option out of the set D. How would one go about achieving this?
I'm somewhat new to gurobi so I don't have much experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an **ordered** set of demand values

```
D = {1, 5, 10, 15, 17}
```

You can create a binary decision variable `Xi` where `i` indicates the position of each demand value. You can add a constraint `sum of Xi == 1` which ensures only one demand value is selected. When you need to use a demand value, you can then use `Di*Xi` where `Di` is the value from the set `D[i]`.

I don't know the exact problem you are trying to solve. And this solution mentioned above is also untested.